# Delphi Popup Window/Form

Tags: forms, delphi, popup

I am new to Delphi and I am using RAD Studios XE8.  I am developing a windows program that needs an options button.  I am trying to create a form that when the button is hit, it opens the form.  I am having trouble finding out how to do this or a tutorial online.  Any insight would be helpful such as what I should google, or a link to a tutorial on how to do this or a walk-though video.  I have a strong feeling that I may be using the wrong terminology as well.  Any help would be nice.

Comment: Have you started with the program documentation?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Sari wants to quick start developing in Delphi. Reading some 900 pages manuals is not that "quick". I am sure in time he will read more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is something to get you started:

1. Create a forms application (eg. with main form named `Form1`)
2. Create a second form (eg. with name `Form2`)
3. Create a button on first form in designer
4. Double click the button in the designer
5. IDE will open editor and create a handler for you - this is where you have to put the following code: `Form2.Show();`
6. Run and test

I would advise you try at least several tutorials like these before trying to write your own program:

- [Delphi for beginners: My First Delphi Program](http://delphi.about.com/od/beginners/l/aa020299.htm)
- [Simple calculator tutorial](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Simple_Calculator_Tutorial)

Comment: I fallowed your instructions.  I also added the new form to the 'uses'.  I receive an error saying "Form2 does not contain a member named 'Show()' ".  What else do i need to do?

Comment: If you are creating VCL Forms Application and VCL Forms with the right names it should work. Did you create a VCL Form and does your Form2 file (Unit2) contain the variable declaration `Form2: TForm2;`?

Comment: i needed to plast the form name in front of it "PopUpForm.Form2.Show();"